# meaning of kumpel in given context

Tags: meaning-in-context

When german girl say this

> bin 13 uhr bei einem kumpel und vorher kann ich mich nicht motivieren

then here she is talking about her boyfriend or some girl whose is her close friend?

So here Kumpel means what ? a boyfriend or just a friend who can be girl or just a male friend ?

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/kumpel Definitely not _boyfriend_.

Answer (score 4):

The link πάντα ῥεῖ gave in his comment already shows a wide range of possible English translations.
A *Kumpel* is male friend, but the use of this word instead of *Freund* expressly states that there is no romantic or sexual relationship.

Comment: In nowadays colloquial German young people often use _Kollege_. As far as I know, _Kumpel_ is not 'süddeutsch' and tends to be understood as '_buddy_' (_er ist ein echter Kumpel_). It is sloppier than _friend_. A close friendship, sexual or not, will be marked by possessive articles (_ihr Freund_). If it's just friendship 'without ulterior motives' you might call the relationship _ihr bester Freund / seine beste Freundin_.

Comment: Kollege means co-worker, and I have never heard the use of this word for anyone who was not working at least for the same employer (but maybe in totally different departments, not really working together). On the other hand, I'm not a member of the younger generation any more.